# Python Regular Expressions - Complete Match

Tags: python, regex

for my CGI application I'm writing a function to get the browser's preferred language (supplied in the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE variable). I want to find all language tags in this variable with regular expressions (The general pattern of a language tag is defined in [RFC1766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1766)). EBNF from RFC1766 ('1*8ALPHA' means one to eight ASCII chars):

```
Language-Tag = Primary-tag *( "-" Subtag )
Primary-tag = 1*8ALPHA
Subtag = 1*8ALPHA
```

I wrote this regular expression for a language tag:

```
(([a-z]{1,8})(-[a-z]{1,8})*)
```

If i use this expression, Python's re module supplies the following

```
>>import re

>>re.findall("(([a-z]{1,8})(-[a-z]{1,8})*)", "x-pig-latin en-us de-de en", re.IGNORECASE)
[('x-pig-latin', 'x', '-latin'), ('en-us', 'en', '-us'), ('de-de', 'de', '-de'), ('en', 'en', '')]
```

The result is correct. But I only need complete matches like 'de-de' or 'x-pig-latin'. Can I assume that the first match of a group is always the most complete one? Or is there a flag telling re to show the most complete matches?

Stefan

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ?: operator to prevent the regex engine from saving bracketed subpatterns:

```
((?:[a-z]{1,8})(?:-[a-z]{1,8})*)
```

This gives the output:

```
re.findall("((?:[a-z]{1,8})(?:-[a-z]{1,8})*)", "x-pig-latin en-us de-de en", re.IGNORECASE)
['x-pig-latin', 'en-us', 'de-de', 'en']
```

To answer your question, the first match returned by findall should be the full matching substring.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly I'm looking for. I never used the ?: operator before.

Answer (score 2):

Make your inner groups (i.e., parentheses) into *non*-capturing ones: that is, change from:

```
(([a-z]{1,8})(-[a-z]{1,8})*)
```

to:

```
((?:[a-z]{1,8})(?:-[a-z]{1,8})*)
```

To recap, the pattern notation `(?: ... )` defines a **non**-capturing group: the parentheses stills serve the purpose of controlling priority, but don't leave traces in the match object's `.groups()` and other capturing-group related traits.

Plain parentheses, `( ... )`, mean a **capturing** group.

There is no reason to use capturing groups for sub-matches that you're explicitly *not* interested about, of course.  Use them only for the sub-matches you **do** care about!-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already checked it out, but [this article](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/04/more-i-dig-through-code-more-paste-is.html) has lots of good pointers about doing `Accept-Language` parsing, along with a reference to a library that has already solved the problem.

As far as your `re` question goes, Doug Hellman has a [great breakdown of `re`](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/re/) in his recent Python Module of the Week.